# Update Entry MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use CandleStick chart. And I need to make the last candle update its close value in realtime. 
What I tried:

```
CandleEntry lastEntry = getCandleData().getDataSetByIndex(0).getEntryForXIndex(candleDataSetEntryCount);
lastEntry.setClose(newClose);
getCandleData().notifyDataChanged();
notifyDataSetChanged();
invalidate();
```

Or
    (tried to remove last entry and add a new one instead of it)

```
getCandleData().getDataSetByIndex(0).removeLast();
getCandleData().notifyDataChanged();
notifyDataSetChanged();

getCandleData().addXValue("0");
getCandleData().addEntry(new CandleEntry(getCandleData().getDataSetByIndex(0).getEntryCount(), oldHigh, oldLow, oldOpen, newClose), 0);
notifyDataSetChanged();
invalidate();
```

The code works if I only keep deleting last entry or adding a new entry, but it does not when I try to replace old entry with a new one.
P.S. If I log the value of 'changed' entry - it is actually changed, seems like it's drawn with the old pixels data.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it out what was the problem. 
There is a bug in lib and the lib doesn't draw the last candle. It stops on the second to last entry. 
The problem is in calculating the 'maxx' value in method drawDataSet().

Change

```
while ( maxx < entries.size() -1 && entries.get(maxx).getXIndex() < mMaxDisplayedIndex+1 ) maxx++;
```

to

```
while ( maxx <= entries.size() -1 && entries.get(maxx).getXIndex() <= mMaxDisplayedIndex+1 ) maxx++;
```

After this, chart draws the last entry and you can easily access the last entry, change it's values, call notifyDataSetChanged() and invalidate().